# Answering your own question multiple times

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, answers, community-wiki

I'm asking this because of the following question on SU:

[What’s the easiest to use ‘find a time to schedule meeting’ tool you’ve used?](https://superuser.com/questions/29721/whats-the-easiest-to-use-find-a-time-to-schedule-meeting-tool-youve-used)

It was originally posted without being CW which would have been fair enough if the OP didn't plan on answering the question 5 times. I commented, probably wrongly, saying that it should be CW if the OP was going to answer 5 times. Really the answers should just have been made CW allowing others to take rep from it.

The above is irrelevant to my question.

I thought it was actually a clever little scheme to poll your own question like that to get opinions on what people.

Is this ok? I liked it but it should be 100% mandatory for the answers to be CW.

Maybe something can be implemented to "auto-wiki" several answers made in quick succession.

Edit: Based on the answers given, maybe this would be better viewed as a feature request. It seems OK that a question be asked and answered like this; the answers made by the OP *need* to be CW'd to prevent gaming though

Answer (score 2):

It's a fine technique, if you really must do a poll. Back when it took only a single vote to close a question, I was of the opinion that a Proper Poll on SO would be one where the author posted the questions, all answers, and then close it to prevent any other answers from being added. Sadly, this is quite difficult to accomplish these days.

Of course, all answers should be marked Community Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the question/answers are CW, I see no harm.

Keep in mind that people are less likely to answer the question, and that most questions were this will be applicable are likely not appropriate for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with it, per se.

But I won't touch them if they are not CW (question and answers).

The one you linked looks too much like gaming the system for me.

Comment: Why would you think this is gaming the system?  I can't get any points from a CW can I?  I really want an answer as I didn't feel like testing all 5, now 6, sites myself.  Looks like this approach isn't very useful anyway as no one has voted up an answer.

Comment: Because--at least initially--none of the answers were CW. **BTW:** my current organization uses Doodle for that with reasonable success, but I don't like it much.